# Añadir un AAR dentro de otro

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un sdk en formato `.AAR`, el cual depende de otra librería `.AAR`.

Estas librerías son locales, no es posible utilizar repositorios Maven para subirlos.

Al generar el `.AAR` la otra librería aparece vacía, por lo que fallan las dependencias.

Es posible hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Un [AAR](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#aar-contents) es similar a un .JAR, en realidad es un archivo comprimido que contiene el proyecto library

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si deseas agregar otro .AAR a esta library lo que debes realizar es agregarlo como dependencia y esto incluirá tu .AAR en el proyecto (.AAR):

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/myPablo.aar')
}
```

Comment: si, eso funciona, pero cuando genero el aar con assembleRelease las dependencias del otro aar no están dentro

Comment: Me llama la atención lo que comentas ya que la dependencia esta definiendo un archivo dentro de /libs similar a cuando agregamos .JAR , ¿Tu archivo lo agregas dentro de el directorio /libs?

Comment: He probado en libs, como módulo, incluso descomprimiendo el zip y añadiéndolo, pero no sirve, lo que debería hacer es mergear los dos .aar en uno, ya que ambos tienen resources, manifest etc